# Optional virutal function in extended class, test if it exists at runtime

Tags: c++, oop

```cpp
class A {
public:
    void (*_start)() = 0;
    void start() {
        cout<<"Le ";
        if (_start!=0) _start();
    }
    A() {}
};
class B : public A {
public:
    void _start() {
        cout<<"Blop";
    }
    B(){}
};
class C : public A {
public:
    C(){}
};

int main () {//Desired results:
  B().start(); //Le Blop
  C().start(); //Le
  return 0;
}
```

The following code above does not run, but in the `main` method I have thier desired outputs.
Is it at all possible to have "optional" virtual methods?  To be able to easily overload and impliment a function in the child class, and have it as some null value in the parent class so that its methods can identify if the function is defined or not.

What I get from the code above is `Le Le`, I assume `_start` in the parent class differs from the `_start` in the child class, not by value, but identity.

If so, how is this done?  I would like to do it in a tidy way, such as, not having to set `_start` in the constructor.

Comment: virtual methods are by definition optional, so their empty implementation in base class is equivalent of this if you actually want to use base class.would you want to access it statically or polymorphically? first one can be dome with CRTP if solution is a little  "wordy"

Comment: I suggest not use underline '_' before names of variables, object etc because it is normally used by C++'s internal objects.

Answer (score 1):

Was alittle silly,

I could simply define the optional function as `virtual void _start() { };` instead of `virtual void _start() = 0;`.  Having the exact same behavior of the desired code above

Resulting in:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual void _start() { };
    void start() {
        cout<<"Le ";
        _start();
    }
    A() {}
};
class B : public A {
public:
    void _start() {
        cout<<"Blop";
    }
    B(){}
};
class C : public A {
public:
    C(){}
};

int main () {//Desired results:
  B().start(); //Le Blop
  C().start(); //Le
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, if that's what you wanted  for it to behave, yes. There are more esoteric use-cases :P

Comment: Would still be good to be able to set the method to some null value, and have the option to test if the method is defined at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Without virtual methods, you might do:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B() {
        _start = [](){ std::cout<<"Blop\n";};
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4af7ae8a42d9104a)

But you don't need inheritance in fact:

```
int main () {
    A a1{[](){ std::cout<<"Blop\n";}};
    A a2;
    a1.start(); //Le Blop
    a2.start(); //Le
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8d475d46a3eca07)

`void (*_start)()` could be replaced by `std::function<void()> _start;` to allow more functors (as capturing lambda).

Answer (score 0):

The classes B and C don't exist without class A and class A is part of B and C respectively. With this in mind, class A shouldn't worry if it is inherited by other classes.

With this in mind, you can simplify the code. Below you can find an example houw the code could be:

```
struct A {
    void start() {
         cout << "Le ";
    }
};

struct B : public A {
    void start() {
         A::start();
         cout << "Blop\n";
    }
};

struct C : public A {
    void start() {
         A::start();
    }
};

int main () {
    B b;
    C c;

    b.start();
    c.start();

  return 0;
}
```